# How can I expand QTabWidget's tabs?

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qtabwidget, qtwidgets, qtabbar

I have three QTabWidget tabs, but there is a big margin on their right:

[image]

I want to remove it by expanding my three tabs.

How can I do that? Can I use QStackedWidget to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expand tabs in QTabWidget Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252403/how-to-expand-tabs-in-qtabwidget-qt). (See also: [PyQT5 QTabbar Expand tab header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65749732/984421)).